# Show/Get runtime, os, device contexts from Sentry Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, scope, sentry

I am trying to get the *runtime*, *os* and/or *device* context/information that Sentry measures when send a event, for example:
[image]

I want to recycle that information in a react-native app to send to my API and make analytics; so that information must be in a normal JavaScript object and need to be acquire in any moment, not only when the app crash and Sentry send events ;).

Can you help me with this, I only find forms to *setContext* and complete that information, but not how get it in runtime.

Thank you every one for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those informations are collected by Sentry via their Native integrations (https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native).

I propose You to get those informations on Your own via
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info

The base OS build the product is based on:

```
DeviceInfo.getBaseOs().then(baseOs => {
  // "Windows", "Android" etc
});
```

Get the device name:

```
DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().then(deviceName => {
  // iOS: "Becca's iPhone 6"
  // Android: ?
  // Windows: ?
});
```